# why list-group doesn't take full width of the column

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm working on angular. I have added a list-group. But it's doesn't take the full width of the column. It grows his width according to the content of the list-item.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <app-shopping-edit></app-shopping-edit>
      <hr>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <a href="" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
          {{ingredient.name}} ({{ingredient.amount}})
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[This is the screenshot of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UjOf.png)

Comment: which version of bootstrap-4 are you using? From the screenshot, `col-xs-10` doesn't look like it's taking up 10 columns out of 12 to me...

Comment: Bootstrap 4.1 does not have class `col-xs-10`. If you means it refer to extra small breakpoint use `col-10` instead.  `col-10` does not means having 10 columns but bootstrap use 12 columns that means it will take 10 columns. Extra small, class prefix `col-` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't aware of it